# MS Teams integration - tenant administrator permission issue

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have recently integrated MS teams API so that clients can directly schedule their meetings from our dashboard. The integration worked fine and everything worked when we tested internally. Now however when clients tried to use this integration, they are facing issues.
When they are taken to authorization screen and they approve the request, it says "Sorry, but we're having trouble with signing you in"

and the `Troubleshooting details` says:
Application with identifier was not found in the director. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant...

I've attached screenshot here. The permission/scope we are using are: `OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite, offline_access`

I already asked this question on MS forum but didn't get any answer there yet. Adding link here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/339273/ms-teams-integration-tenant-administrator-permissi.html
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is your Application registration configured for a single tenant or multitenant?

Comment: You seem to have registered the application as a single-tenant (for your organization, and not for the client's). It needs to be multi-tenant, or you need to register it in the client's AD not yours. Please note for multi-tenant if you don't request ADMIN consent but USER consent, you'll need to add your MPN ID to the app registration. OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite does not require admin consent.

Comment: thankyou both. how can I make it multi tenant?

Comment: You need to enable the multi tenant in azure where you have registered your application.

Answer (score 0):

To access the application for other organisation, you need to  enable the multi tenant configuration in application registration.You need to enable the multi tenant in azure where you have registered your application. Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2#register-a-new-application-using-the-azure-portal) for more info.